# Problem with referring to methods in classes in python

Tags: python

i have this code:

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        Contact.name = name
        Contact.phone = phone
class AddContact:
    def __init__(self):
        self.People = []
    def add_people(self, x):
       self.People.append(x)
    def print_contact(self):
        for x in self.People:
            print("name:" + x.name)
            print("phone:", x.phone)

while True:
    print("----MENU----")
    print("1 -> add contact")
    print("2 -> contact list")
    choice = int(input("enter your choice: "))
    if choice == 1:
        name = input("enter the name of the contact: ")
        phone = input("enter the phone number of the contact: ")
        person = Contact(name, phone)
        AddContact.add_people(person)
    if choice == 2:
        AddContact.print_contact()
```

what im trying to make is a contact book where the user can add and view all of his contacts, ive recently learned classes and thought this was the correct way to make it but i get issues the erros im getting is that the parameters x and self are unfilled on this line:

```
def add_people(self, x):
```

when i call them below outside of the class, ive been trying but i dont understand the problem and would like some assistance.
thanks is advance.

Comment: You are calling ***instance*** methods without an instance. Instead of `AddContact.add_people()` you want `AddContact().add_people()` or probably `contact = AddContact() ; contact.add_people()`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `AddContact` wrong. You need to create an instance of it (just like you created an instance of `Contact`).

While we are at it, `PhoneBook` would be a much better name for this class.

```py
...
class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.People = []

    def add_people(self, x):
       self.People.append(x)

    def print_contact(self):
        for x in self.People:
            print("name:" + x.name)
            print("phone:", x.phone)


phone_book = PhoneBook()

while True:
    print("----MENU----")
    print("1 -> add contact")
    print("2 -> contact list")
    
    choice = int(input("enter your choice: "))
    
    if choice == 1:
        name = input("enter the name of the contact: ")
        phone = input("enter the phone number of the contact: ")
        person = Contact(name, phone)
        phone_book.add_people(person)

    if choice == 2:
        phone_book.print_contact()
```

Comment: yup, was about to say this as well. Currently the class is defined as if it is meant to be instantiated, but used as if those methods were class methods